# Spatial point process: Homogeneous vs inhomogeneous K-function

Tags: spatial, point-process

I wonder when would you use a homogeneous K-function instead of a inhomogeneous one and what advantage it has over inhomogeneous K-function? In my opinion I think we should always use inhomogeneous one.

Answer (score 0):

You can always apply both, but the question is, if it makes sense. The homogeneous $K$-function was defined for stationary point processes, while "The inhomogeneous" $K$-function was defined for a special class of inhomgeneous point processes, the so-called "second-order intensity reweighted stationary" (soirs) point processes, see [Baddeley, Møller and Waagepetersen (2000)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/1467-9574.00144).

When the conditions (stationarity or soirs) are not fulfilled, the theoretical value of the (inhomogeneous) $K$-function depends on the placement of the observation window, and thus the interpretation of estimation result is somewhat dubious. A statistical test for the underlying assumptions can be found in the paper  [Hahn and Jensen (2015)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/sjos.12185), together with alternative definitions of inhomogeneous $K$-functions that are adapted to other particular classes of inhomogeneous point processes: transformation-inhomogeneous and locally scaled point processes.